# Google visualization Script Issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a dashboard to represent some data I have in a google spreadsheet and I have followed the Google charts guides as best as I could (I am not a programmer). I have come up with the script below which is not working and I would like some help in getting it to work.

Here's the  link to my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2wjSj0IYSrA-dwYYly6rjmtw_zMCB6l7FB5B-rcvZc/edit#gid=1303777890

The data I am trying to show as a column chart is in Sheet2 (Data2) columns D and E (highlighted), and I added that range to the url query "`range=D:E`"

The code that I have come up with is below. I just want to get it to show the chart. Any help is appreciated.

```
enter code here<html>
```

```
  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.

function drawSheetName() {
  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT D, E');

  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2wjSj0IYSrA-dwYYly6rjmtw_zMCB6l7FB5B-rcvZc/edit#gid=1303777890range=D:E');
  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, { height: 400 });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the problem.

```
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.

function drawSheetName() {
  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT D, E');

  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2wjSj0IYSrA-dwYYly6rjmtw_zMCB6l7FB5B-rcvZc/edit#gid=1303777890range=D:E');
  query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}
```

You used the `drawSheetName()` but didn't call it in the `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback()`.

## Code Revision

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSheetName)
```

Then for the

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2wjSj0IYSrA-dwYYly6rjmtw_zMCB6l7FB5B-rcvZc/edit#gid=1303777890range=D:E');
```

Change the format to

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
            'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/gviz/tq?tq='+queryString);
```

## Query Language Reference

> The Google Visualization API Query Language lets you perform various data manipulations with the query to the data source.

[**Setting the Query in the Data Source URL**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#setting-the-query-in-the-data-source-url)

> The query string can be added to the data source URL using the `tq` parameter. Setting the query in the URL parameter instead of in JavaScript allows you to easily use visualizations written by other developers, and still be able to customize the query.
>
> The query string must be properly encoded as a URL parameter. You can encode a URL using the JavaScript `encodeURIComponent` function, or you can encode it by hand, using the encoding tool at the end of this section.

For additional information and sample:

- [Google Chart Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)